# MySQL query cache vs caching result-sets in the application layer

Tags: php, mysql, performance, caching, query-cache

I'm running a php/mysql-driven website with a lot of visits and I'm considering the possibility of caching result-sets in shared memory in order to reduce database load.
However, right now MySQL's query cache is enabled and it seems to be doing a pretty good job since if I disable query caching, the use of CPU jumps to 100% immediately.
Given that situation, I dont know if caching result-sets (or even the generated HTML code) locally in shared memory with PHP will result in any noticeable performace improvement.

Does anyone out there have any experience on this matter?

PS: Please avoid suggesting heavy-artillery solutions like memcached. Right now I'm looking for simple solutions that dont require too much time to implement, deploy and maintain.

**Edit:**
I see my comment about memcached deviated answers from the actual point, which is whether caching DB queries in the application layer would result in a noticeable performace impact considering that the result of those queries are already being cached at the DB level.

Comment: What does your data usage look like?  Mostly reads and very few writes, or is there lots of write activity as well?

Comment: CPU usage spiking to 100% is fishy. Most databases end up IO bound, not CPU bound.

Comment: There are lots of writes, but I managed to arrange tables in such a way that most queried tables are modified less often. That's why MySQL's query cache is working pretty well.

Answer (score 3):

I know you didn't want to hear about memcached, but it *is* one of the best solutions for what you're trying to do. Depending on your site usage, there can be massive improvements in performance. By simply using memcached's session handler over my database session handler, I was able to cut the load in half and cut back on request serving times by over 30%.

Realistically, memcached is a simple solution. It's already integrated with PHP (if you have the extension loaded), and it requires virtually no configuration (I simply had to add memcached as a service on my linux box, which is done in one or two shell commands).

I would suggest storing session data (and anything that lends itself to caching) in memcache. For dynamic pages (such as stack overflow homepage), I would recommend caching output for a couple of seconds to prevent flooding.

Answer (score 0):

A decent single box solution is file-based caching, but you have to sweep them out manually. Other than that, you could use APC, which is very fast and in-memory (still have to expire them yourself though).

As soon as you scale past one web server, though, you're going to need a shared cache, which is memcached. Why are you so adamant about not deploying this? It's not hard, and it's just going to save you time down the road. You can either start using memcache now and be done with it, or you could use one of the above methods for now and then end up switching to memcache later anyways, resulting in even more work. Plus too, you don't have to deal with running a cronjob or some other ugly hack to get cache expiration features: it does that for you.

The mysql query cache is nice, but it's not without [issues](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/07/27/mysql-query-cache/). One of the big ones is it expires automatically every time the source data is changed, which you probably don't want.